# Websocket connection never goes to the open state

Tags: c#, javascript, google-chrome, websocket

I got a small C# server for websockets. The connection seems to be getting established well but the onopen function of my websocket on the javascript side is never getting called for some reason, so the connection basically never opens properly.

```
Debug.WriteLine("Client connected");
writer.WriteLine("HTTP/1.1 101 Web Socket Protocol Handshake");
writer.WriteLine("Upgrade: WebSocket");
writer.WriteLine("Connection: Upgrade");
writer.WriteLine("WebSocket-Origin: http://localhost:8080");
writer.WriteLine("WebSocket-Location: ws://localhost:8181/websession");
writer.WriteLine("");
```

There is the code I send back to the client.

And here is the code on the javascript side

```
function openSocket()
{
    var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8181/websession");


    ws.onclose = function()
    {
        alert("state is: " + ws.readyState);
        alert('connection closed!');
    }


    ws.onopen = function()
    {
        alert('handshake established');
    }

}
```

The onopen function never gets called, even if my server receives the connection request and answers to it. The onclose function instead gets called. Any ideas what I might be doing wrong? The problem is most likely in the c# portion as the chrome part works fine.

Comment: You are missing the `Sec-WebSocket-Accept` header. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket#WebSocket_protocol_handshake

Comment: Please refer to the specification(s) - here's r13: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6455 - you are missing the all-important "yes I know what I'm doing and I'm proving it with some maths" header. Alsi - the origin is sent by the client, not the server.

Comment: So after I do the math and the line, it should work fine? Everything else is correct?